# Twilio Microphone Issues

Tags: twilio

So we have built a custom system with Twilio that accepts calls in the browser. An issue I am having is one of our operators took a call with a team member in skype. Once they went back to the browser it seems like their microphone was not working right.

Is there anyway to fix this issue? Like, I think for some reason after they hung up on skype the microphone wasn't in sync with the chrome browser in twilio and would not connect the user to the call.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

On some operating systems camera and microphone devices cannot be shared between applications. My guess here is that Skype took over the access to the microphone and the web application lost that access.

I've not tested this myself, but you might consider trying to listen to the ["deviceChange" event on the `Twilio.Device.audio` object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#event-twiliodeviceaudiodevicechange) to see if that fires when a microphone is lost by the page. You may be able to recover by triggering `getUserMedia` again, or you may need your user to refresh the page to reconnect to the microphone.

Let me know if that helps at all.